# Remove File from Repository without deleting local copy

Tags: repository, subclipse, working-copy

How do I do this in Subclipse:

```
svn rm --keep-local file
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This option is not exposed in Subclipse.  So you have to stash the file somewhere and then delete it and commit it and put it back locally.